# Filter Logic in SwiftUI - Apple Tutorial

Tags: swiftui, logical-operators

I am working the Landmarks SwiftUI tutorial https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input. I am stumped on the use of the logical operators in

```
landmarks.filter { landmark in
            (!showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite)
        }
```

I am trying to understand how this logic works in returning the filteredLandmarks. I'm pretty sure the ! operator inverts the **showFavoritesOnly** operand and the || operator on **landmark.isFavorite** makes the statement true if either side is true in the closure but for some reason this what is supposed to happen as far as what is returned escapes me at the moment. If anyone can clarify I'd be very appreciative.

Here's the file for context:

```
 import SwiftUI
    
    struct LandmarkList: View {
        @State private var showFavoritesOnly = false
        
        var filteredLandmarks: [Landmark] {
            landmarks.filter { landmark in
                (!showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite)
            }
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List(filteredLandmarks)
                    { landmark in
                    NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Landmarks")
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
                LandmarkList()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure the **! operator inverts the showFavoritesOnly** operand and the **|| operator on landmark.isFavorite makes the statement true if either side is true**

You are completely right.

> but for some reason this **what is supposed to happen as far as what is returned** escapes me at the moment.

The [`filter(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) method lets you *filter* an array (remove elements that don't satisfy a condition).

It takes in a closure, `isIncluded`. This closure is called once for each element in the array, with the current element passed into the parameter:

```
               /// ↓ the current element in the array
landmarks.filter { landmark in }
```

This closure must return a `Bool`, which represents if the element should be kept.

- So if it returns `true`, that means keep the element
- If `false`, then remove the element

In your implementation, you're keeping the elements whose `showFavoritesOnly` is false OR `isFavorite` is true.

```
landmarks.filter { landmark in
    (!showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite) /// return the Bool
}
```

Maybe you're confused as to why there's not a return statement...

```
landmarks.filter { landmark in
    return (!showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite)
}
```

The reason is because the `return` keyword is optional when you only have one expression. If you did something like:

```
landmarks.filter { landmark in
    let elementShouldBeKept = (!showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite)
    return elementShouldBeKept
}
```

... then you'd need the `return`.

Comment: @JamesH the `!` operator **does not** affect `showFavoritesOnly`. It **checks** if it's true or false, then evaluates to the opposite. `showFavoritesOnly` is never modified.

Comment: @shaze I think I get it. That's a good answer. So, if showFavoritesOnly is initialized to false the ! operator inverts it it true for evaluation in the closure and thus there is no need to check landmark.isFavorite after the || since the closure has already determined the closure is true. Thus every element in [Landmark] array will be returned. That's what I'm getting out of this, in a way.

Comment: @JamesH exactly! And if `showFavoritesOnly` is true, then `!showFavoritesOnly` will be false, so it's up to `landmark.isFavorite` to determine if the element will be kept.

Answer (score 1):

`!showFavoritesOnly` is the same as saying `if (showFavoritesOnly == false) return true`

So, when evaluating for the filtered list:
If `!showFavoritesOnly`, it has no need to evaluate the rest of the statement as a 'true' is returned, and the element is placed in the list to be shown (ie an unfiltered list of all elements in this case, as every element will evaluate to `showFavoritesOnly == false`).

However, once `showFavoritesOnly` becomes true, the computer then evaluates the next half of the statement.

I made a flowchart which helps me visualise this concept:

[image: Flowchart]